# How to create Qr code with multiple variable on a single QR code?

Tags: android, qr-code

My application project have qr code generator feature. I use the Zxing library to coding qr code generator, but it can generate qr code only single variable. i want to create qr code with 3 variable on a single qr code. please help me to create this.
p.s. I'm a rookie for Android.

my code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat;
import com.google.zxing.MultiFormatWriter;
import com.google.zxing.WriterException;
import com.google.zxing.common.BitMatrix;
import com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeEncoder;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText editText , editText2 , editText3;
private String qrText1 , qrText2 , qrText3;
private ImageView qrCodeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   editText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText);
   editText2 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
   editText3 = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

   Button generateBtn = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.generateButton);
   qrCodeView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

   generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         qrText1 = editText.getText().toString().trim();
         qrText2 = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
         qrText3 = editText3.getText().toString().trim();

         MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
         try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(qrText1, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            qrCodeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

         } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   });
 }
}
```

I don't know how to add qrText2 and qrText3 with qrText1 on create a single qr code.

Comment: AFAIK, a QR code is generated from a string. You can assemble that string however you like. You might want to edit your question and provide a [mcve], showing your code that is using "only single variable", then explain what problems you have encountered when trying to use more variables.

Comment: You can use Gson to create a json object which includes multiple variables. Then simply send the json object. (I did it [here](https://github.com/arop/cafe-payment-system/blob/master/CafeClientApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/joao/cafeclientapp/cart/QrCodeCheckoutActivity.java))

Answer (score 0):

```
generateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        qrText1 = editText.getText().toString().trim();
        qrText2 = editText2.getText().toString().trim();
        qrText3 = editText3.getText().toString().trim();

        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode("Text1 :"+ qrText1 + "\n 
Text2"+ qrText2 +"\n Text3"+ qrText3 , BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200, 200);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            qrCodeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (WriterException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.